# Looking for a story: Tire yard on the moon

Tags: story-identification, moon, wormhole

In a bar, someone told me a story about some scrapyard-guy who accepts (worthless and non-reusable) junk for really low prices and people start to wonder how he disposes it, they try to find out how he does it and they see him getting that stuff into a building he always keeps closed to outsider-eyes. In this building, it turns out, there is a wormhole and all the stuff he throws inside this hole turns up on the surface of the moon, where it's never found and there's practically an endless amount of space for more junk.

I forgot the author, but it might have been Asimov, but I was never able to find the story. Does anyone here know who it's from and what it's name is?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

"[The Hole in the Hole](http://clarkesworldmagazine.com/bisson_06_15_reprint/)" by Terry Bison ([ISFDB](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?40511)). Summary from [here](http://www.technovelgy.com/ct/Science-Fiction-News-Comments.asp?NewsNum=1031):

> "Sci-Fi author Terry Bisson wrote a humorous short story called "The Hole in the Hole" in which the main character discovers a portal that opens onto the surface of the moon in a junkyard. He and a companion attempt to retrieve the lunar rover so they can sell it for a bundle."
> (chelymorpha 5/10/2007 9:13:55 PM)

From the story (accessible in the first link):

> There was a cool breeze and a funny smell. Behind me I heard a steady pop, pop, pop. But when I finished and took the brake parts to Frankie, the pile of tires was still the same size. Frankie was on top of it, leaning on the fence, talking with an Indian man in a Goodyear shirt.
> The Indian (who must have been standing on a truck on the other side of the fence) saw me and ducked. I had scared him away. I realized I was witnessing some kind of illegal dumping operation. I wondered how all the junk tires fit into the tiny shed, but I wasn’t about to ask. Probably Frankie and the old man took them out and dumped them into Jamaica Bay at night.

....

> “Wu,” I said, as soon as Frankie had left to find his uncle, “let me tell you something about junkyard men. You can’t say ‘I’ll take it, I’ll take it’ around them. You have to say, ‘Maybe it might do, or . . . ’”
> “Irving!” Wu cut me off. His eyes were wild. (He hardly ever called me Irving.) He took both my hands in his, as if we were bride and groom, and began to walk me in a circle. His fingers were freezing. “Irving, do you know, do you realize, where we just were?”
> “Some sort of cave? Haven’t we played this game before?”
> “The Moon! Irving, that was the surface of the Moon you just saw!”
> “I admit it was weird,” I said. “But the Moon is a million miles away. And it’s up in the . . . ”

Found with `short story junkyard portal moon`

Comment: Found on the first page of Google Search for *short story junkyard portal moon*

Comment: @RCTXP: If this is the correct answer, please don't forget to accept it by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons.

Comment: Perfect, that was exactly what I was looking for!